# \xmark gives out 7 rather than a cross mark

Tags: pifont

I defined `\xmark` and `\cmark` as follow but when I run it, the number 7 (for `\xmark`) and 3 (for `\cmakr`) is presented on my file. I have no idea with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\xmark E(L^2) &=& E(L\cdot L)\\\
       &=& E(L)\cdot E(L)\\\
       &=& \mu_l \cdot \mu_l\\\
       &=& \mu_l^2
       \\\
\cmark E(L \cdot K) &=& E(L) \cdot E(K) \text{ \small{if $L$ and $K$ are stochastic independent}}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) your do does not compile (needs `amsmath for the `\text` command. (2) never use eqnarray, it is horribly broken, here is a survey: http://tug.org/pracjourn/2012-1/madsen.html, (3) pifont is a text font, thus may behave strangely in math. Try wrapping the `\ding{...}` in `\text...`

Comment: `\xmark` is a text command and its behavior in math is unpredictable. If you need it in math, just do `\newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}` with `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are other similar questions on the site, for different symbol fonts. The main problem is that `\ding{51}` acts by

1. opening a group;
2. selecting the pi font;
3. typesetting character number 51;
4. closing the group.

However, step 2 is completely ineffective when TeX is in math mode, so step 3 tells the program to typeset the *math* character corresponding to 51, which is a 3.

Solution: enclose the call in `\text`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\text{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\xmark
  E(L^2)       &= E(L\cdot L) \\
               &= E(L)\cdot E(L) \\
               &= \mu_l \cdot \mu_l \\
               &= \mu_l^2 \\
\cmark
  E(L \cdot K) &= E(L) \cdot E(K) \text{ if $L$ and $K$ are stochastic independent}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Notes: `eqnarray` should never be used; `\small` doesn't take an argument, and in this case it's not needed (and it would unbalance the display).

[image]